# IVP problem with series involved

Tags: power-series, initial-value-problems

Find a series solution to the following initial value problem:

$x''(t) + 2tx'(t) − 8x(t) = 0 ∀t > 0$ subject to $x(0) = 1$ and $x'(0) = 0$

Ive got that $x(t) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_{n}t^{n}$,

$x'(t) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty na_{n}t^{n-1}$

and $x''(t) = \sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty (n-1)na_{n}t^{n-2}$

But I need some guidance through this question as I seem to always go wrong somewhere.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to shift your series when you differentiate, otherwise it doesn't match your original series. $x'$ should start at $n = 1$, $x''$ at $n = 2$. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1185762/solution-to-ode-using-power-series/1185929#1185929) for a step by step guide.

Comment: I made a mistake when typing the question. Ive changed the n values on x'(t) and x''(t) @Mattos

Comment: So far ive got: $\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty (n-1)na_{n}t^{n-2}+2t\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty na_{n}t^{n-1}-8\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_{n}t^{n}$. Is this right?? @Mattos

Comment: Yes that is right, though remember it is equal to zero. Keep following the steps in the link.